# JQGrid change data before post

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, datepicker

I have one field that is the type date(), that I need to change before sending the data to the server.
By default jqgrid uses yy-mm-dd, but I need to use dd-mm-yy, but before posting the data to the server, the data have to be in yy-mm-dd (date() mysql format). How can I do this?

> , {
>                   name: 'dataini',
>                   index: 'dataini',
>                   formatter:dateFormatter,
>                   width: 80,
>                   align: "center",
>                   editable:true,
>                   editoptions: {
>                       dataInit: function(element) {
>                           $(element).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'})//jquery date plugin
>                       } 
>                   }
>               }
>
> function dateFormatter (cellvalue, options, rowObject)
>       {
>           var fdata = cellvalue.split("-");
>           return fdata[2] + '-' + fdata[1] + '-' + fdata[0];
>       }

Edit: http://pastebin.com/b7ZFuiJS Full Code

Comment: It's important to know which editing mode You use.

Comment: I'm using json.
I'll edit the post with the complete code, but its using local data, for the purpose now, is just for studying.
This is what I want to get http://prntscr.com/4uv024

Comment: Editing Mode can be form Editing, inline editing or cell editing.